# If the parameter supplied while calling a function contains space, function is not called

Tags: javascript, php, last.fm

I'm using last.fm api. I am having a JavaScript AJAX Function which is like this,

```
function showart(art) {
    if (art=="") {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="";
    return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","5.php?a="+art,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And here's the PHP code where I'm calling it.

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
    echo '<table><td width="36px">';
    echo '<img src="'.$info->topartists->artist[$i-1]->image.'"></td>';
    echo '<td><a class="artist" href=# onclick=showart(\''.$info->topartists->artist[$i-1]->name.'\')>'.$info->topartists->artist[$i-1]->name.'</a></td></table>';
}
```

Whenever `$info->topartists->artist[$i-1]->name` is having a space within an artist's name for example, 'Mobb Deep', the function isn't getting called and if the artist's name is for example, 'Adele', the function is getting called. How to fix this?

Comment: That ActiveX call is not necessary unless you're supporting IE6, for whatever that's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode the parameter value:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","5.php?a=" + encodeURIComponent(art), true);
```

That'll encode the space properly and the server will decode it.

*edit* the code that's creating the `<a>` tags is not putting the "onclick" attribute value in quotes, so when the HTML is parsed the event handler code ends up being broken. You should quote the code:

```
echo '<td><a class="artist" href=# onclick="showart(\''.$info->topartists->artist[$i-1]->name.'\')">'.$info->topartists->artist[$i-1]->name.'</a></td></table>';
```

Note the added `"` quotes around the `showart()` call.

Comment: it isn't working, I guess the supplied parameter is to be encoded too or something.

Comment: @VermaJr. how do you know it isn't working? Have you checked for errors in the developer console? Have you checked the outgoing HTTP request from the console? Have you done any debugging on the server? The `encodeURIComponent()` call is definitely necessary, but there could be any number of other things wrong.

Comment: when i'm clicking on the link named 'Coldplay', the results are shown and when I click 'Linkin Park', results are not shown. You may take a look at this here: http://musicjack.eu.org/

Comment: If you check the browser console, you'll see that a JavaScript error is being reported. The code is broken before the ajax attempt is even made.

Comment: yeah, so how to fix it?

Comment: @VermaJr. I edited the answer - you're not quoting the overall "onclick" value.